# Task vs await Task in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I'm confused when to one would use async inside a method. Based on my tests both of these methods work the same way. When would you use one vs. other?

```
        // Returns a task which can be awaited in the controller
        private Task<int> RunAsyncTask1()
        {
            Task<int> task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int result = CalculateMeaningOfLife();
                return result;
            });

            return task;
        }

        // Returns an actual value - it too, can be awaited in the controller
        private async Task<int> RunAsyncTask2()
        {
            var task = await Task.Run(() => {
                int result = CalculateMeaningOfLife();
                return result;
            });

            return task; 
        }
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        Task<int> task = RunAsyncTask1(); // Without await - will continue and not wait for result 
        int result = await RunAsyncTask1(); // Main Thread put back in Thread Pool, will wait for result

        Task<int> task = RunAsyncTask2(); // Without await - will continue and not wait for result
        int result = await RunAsyncTask2(); // Main Thread put back in Thread Pool, will wait for result

        return View();
    }
```

Is the only benefit of having "await" keyword WITHIN a method (RunAsyncTask2()) so that you can set up multiple continuations within that method?

Comment: `await` is useful when you are executing more than one task and one is dependant on the other. Also if you were to have more code after the `var task = //...` initialization, `await` guarantees it will get executed *after* the task completes. Of course, if you are just returning the task, then there's no need for `await` in this case.

Comment: The difference between the two is one is "here's a task: blah blah blah" and the other is "here's a task: perform this task: blah blah blah".  There is no good reason to prefer the latter. A task whose sole content is doing a task is not an interesting task.

Comment: Similarly, you might wonder whether it ever makes sense to have an async method that returns `Task<Task<int>>`.  Typically it does not, though this is possible. *Logically* it is always the case that you can "collapse" monads/comonads. That is, a `Maybe<Maybe<int>>` is *logically* the same as a `Maybe<int>`.  A `Task<Task<int>>` is *logically* the same as a `Task<int>`. A `Lazy<Lazy<int>>` is *logically* the same as `Lazy<int>` -- in each, the sense being that when you get the int out of the thing, it's the same int regardless of the number of wraps.

Comment: `When would you use one vs. other?` You would use neither. Avoid `Task.Run` on ASP.NET; it doesn't give you *any* benefit here and only makes your code less efficient and less scalable.

Comment: @Stephen- What do you mean? I though I could run asynchronous processes in MVC. Or at least in Parallel..ie. getting stuff from Db, while processing something else etc

Comment: @BobSwanson: Asynchronous is fine. `Task.Run` is not asynchronous. I don't recommend parallel code on ASP.NET because it can seriously impact your scalability.

Comment: what about the following, if the tasks are unrelated, wouldn't it improve performance?         // Executes SumX, SumY and SumZ in parallel
        Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions {CancellationToken = cts.Token},
            () => sumX = SumX(cts.Token),
            () => sumY = SumY(cts.Token),
            () => sumZ = SumZ(cts.Token));